# Is there a way to query flow hash in Linux user space?

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, hash

Suppose I'm receiving UDP packets and I want to know what network hash has been computed for that flow.  Is there any way to ask the OS what the hash is for a particular socket/flow?

Seems like there should be a way to query skb->hash from userspace but I can't find a way to get that information.

Comment: Why would the OS have computed a hash?

Comment: What do you mean by "network hash"? The hash used by routers for load balancing?

Comment: The hash computed by the NIC and used by OS is described in [kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/scaling.txt) but I've been unable to find a method to query it in userspace.  It would be useful to know the hash value in order to optimize which CPU is used for packet processing.

Comment: Maybe `tcpdump`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You indicate that it's `skb->hash` which needs to be queried. That tricks me into thinking you might be interested in getting per-packet **RSS** hash values rather than some "flow hash" for a series of packets. If that is indeed the case, the answer is yes, there's a way to accomplish the goal.

In Linux, there's `PACKET_MMAP` mechanism. Long story short, this generic API allows an application to set up a Rx/Tx ring `mmap`-ed from the kernel to the user process, bound to a given network interface. Received packets are made available to the application in the ring entries (slots), and each packet is prefixed with a kernel-defined structure enclosing useful meta information. `PACKET_MMAP` mechanism has different API versions and, in particular, `TPACKET_V3` (available starting from ~3.2 kernels) provides RSS hash over there (`hv1.tp_rxhash` at the link below), if requested/configured.

Furthermore, an application may require that packet reception be load balanced among processes (`PACKET_FANOUT_HASH` at the link below).

You should probably take a look at https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/networking/packet_mmap.html for more details and useful code examples.